# File Encoding and Input Encoding

Tags: input-encodings

In order to avoid cluttering other related questions, I separately make this question.

If I use Notepad as my editor, there are 4 encoding options available when saving the TeX input file: ANSI, Unicode, Unicode big endian, and UTF-8.

I want to know which input encoding do I have to use for each file encoding mentioned above.

For example, when I choose Unicode as the file encoding, which input encoding do I have to choose?

Comment: IIRC, Notepad means "UTF16" when saying Unicode. So if you want to use non-ASCII characters without escaping them, you should use UTF8 to save the file and use `utf8` or `utf8x` as option to `inputenc` unless you use lualatex/xelatex as pointed out by Boris. Of course you should consider to use a proper editor or TeX IDE rather than Notepad.

Comment: Notepad++ is a nice candidate. It has a lot of handy features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are using `pdflatex`: both `xelatex` and `lualatex` understand Unicode.

If you have non-ascii characters, your best bet is UTF-8 file with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.  Otherwise choose ANSI and do not use `inputenc`.

However there is a catch: Windows Notepad always saves the BOM (byte-order mark), which LaTeX does not want to see in the input. So if you would like to use a Unicode input encoding, I would not use Windows Notepad (until it lets you specify "UTF-8 without BOM" as a save option).

Comment: Notepad++ can encode a document in UTF-8 without BOM.